# What size is the T-track for Metabo Bs 0633 bandsaw table?

Tags: power-tools, tool-identification, band-saw, fence, miter-slot

Problem: I recently bought a used Metabo Bs 0633 bandsaw but cannot find any marketed t-track attachment for the t-tracks running parallel to the blade.

Question: What is the name or sizing category for a t-track slider for this bandsaw?

Context: I am looking for sliders or bolts or something like that to slide in the track for attachment of jigs and things like this:
[image]

Photo of the bandsaw:
[image]

Photo of bandsaw table showing the rip fence that slide in the miter slot perpendicular to the blade:
[image]

Photo of the bandsaw boiler plate:
[image]

Photo of the t-track lower part: ~19 mm (~3/4")
[image]

Photo of the t-track upper part: ~12 mm (~1/2")
[image]

Photo of the t-track cross section: ~7 mm total depth (~1/4")
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there are categories for T-tracks and accessories beyond "fits my tool" and "doesn't fit my tool". However, it seems you've got all the critical measurements. Take your measuring tools to your nearest specialty store and measure up their stock of accessories to see if they'll fit. You may also want to measure the actual "T" on the fence to see how much smaller it is. If you get an accessory _exactly_ 12mm wide, it may fit, but not slide.

Comment: @FreeMan, *'categories for T-tracks and accessories beyond "fits my tool" and "doesn't fit my tool".'* ^_^

Comment: Just to note, measuring with a rule is likely not going to be accurate enough here to find a perfect fit. You want to use a calipers to get all the relevant dimensions pretty much dead-on. However, if you did get channel that's slightly too wide you can alter it until it's a sliding fit without too much bother. Similarly, if you can only find something that's just a skosh too loose that can be addressed slightly too (using the same technique as for mitre channel that has worn loose over time through use).

Comment: @FreeMan This is indeed what I tried, but found that some T-tracks are labeled "A", "B", "C" from a local store.  [LINK] (https://www.baptist.nl/en/houtbewerkers/routing/accessories-for-routing/t-track-c-60-cm)

There are also some tracks available from Amazon/Aliexpress titled "Type 45" and "Type 19". 

e.g.:
-"Type 45": With slide measure side that is similar in size to my needs: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000282540820.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000023.15.5cad26a567ToBO

-"Type 19": https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H0fa365476b1146499440eacd109e0985G.jpg?width=750&height=1206&hash=1956

Comment: @Graphus Agreed on the calipers. I figured it may be a standardized size that is used on more tools. 

I was actually just thinking to take a carriage bolt and see if it fits well enough. Maybe I need to file down the edges or bottom for some flat sizes. I will let you know when I give it a shot.

Comment: Including that info in the question might have been helpful. ;)  Also it's `[linktext](url)` with no spaces... That said, we've had a few questions about this and there doesn't seem to be much in the way of standards. i.e. each manufacturer and/or country seems to have their own. Your best bet may be to call/write the retailer or manufacturer of the accessory to get the exact dimensions of "A", "B", "C" or "Type 19" and "Type 45".

Comment: Yes just to reiterate what @FreeMan said, there appears to be no standard with these. Often manufacturers would do this to (try to) lock you into buying their accessories only, not that I'm cynical at all.

Comment: @Graphus I hear you on the locking you into their own accessories. It is an "old" Metabo from 1991 (labelled as made in W. Germany... It seems the label maker did not hear about Unification Day). They no longer make these bandsaws or any accessories for them. 

Since I cannot post pictures here, I will try to add an answer (if I have enough points) or edit my question above.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a type of T-track, but a solution I have found is to file off the top and square the edges of the top of a **M8 carriage bolt**. It fits well enough for clamping operations. It has more slop than you may need for proper sliding work. I may not have needed to file the edges down at all.

Filed M8:
[image: M8 Filed top and edges]

Bolt fit into T Track:
[image: Bolt in T Track]

Shown used as a clamp in an adjustable resaw fence:
[image: Clamping a fence]

Comment: Excellent! Self-answers are appropriate _and_ appreciated. Did you file down just the shoulders of the carriage bolt, or did you have to thin down the head, too?

Comment: Thanks! I did have to file down both head and shoulders. I made another and found it better to fully file down the head before the shoulders. That way the shoulder can be tightly dialed in.